# Layout page's code not being sent to content pages

Tags: razor, razor-2, asp.net-webpages

I have a _SiteLayout.cshtml file which structures the site and has some C# code on it. How do I send the _SiteLayout's C# code to all of its subpages? I am using WebPages Razor 2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods for implementing a layout page:

- use the `Layout` command in the code section of every page, as outlined in [Creating a Consistent Layout in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Sites](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/3-creating-a-consistent-look)
- or initialize the same layout page for all files in a single folder using the `_PageStart.cshtml` file([Customizing Site-Wide Behavior for ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Sites](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior)).

In the latter case you could disable the layout page for a single page using `Layout = null` in the code section.

**Edit**

If you want to pass data from a master page to a partial page, you must use the RenderPage() method instead of the RenderBody() method, but the structure of your site fully changes.

If, by example, you want to create a master page that extracts data from a table and passes them to a partial page that can change, your master page could be something like:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Northwind");
    var data = db.Query(@"SELECT [Product Id], [Product Name], 
            [English Name] FROM Products ");
    var page = "Partial.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderPage(page, new {gridData = data})
    </body>
</html>
```

The code in Partial.cshtml takes data from the Page.gridData variable and displays them in a WebGrid:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Page.gridData);
}

<div>@grid.GetHtml()</div>
```

Comment: I'm using the first method, however, the C# code which I do in my Layout page, is not implemented on the pages which uses that Layout page for layout. That's what I need to do, but for some reason, it just doesn't.

Comment: @user3250722 I had misunderstood your question. Now I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had hoped a simple Layout page would also pass the Layout page's C# code to its content pages, but unfortunately not then. In my case I am checking if a user is logged in on the layout page so I don't have to do that same thing for every content page, and I thought it worked, but apparently not, hehe. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user3250722 To secure multiple pages you should use _PageStart.cshtml. Look at this link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=202906#Using__PageStart.cshtml_to_Restrict_Folder_Access